# How to post static content from view to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, static

I have some static content in html page. I want to post this static content in controller in codeigniter. how should i post data

Comment: I think that your static content should be in the view... just because of the  MVC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: Yes its in the view but i want to send to controller. What should i do???

Comment: send your content with the help of form

Answer (score 1):

Use can use `form` tag to send your content from view to controller

VIEW

```
<form action="your_action" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="content" />
 <textarea name="large_content"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" value="SEND" />
</form>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function your_function()
{
 $content = $this->input->post('content');
 $large_content = $this->input->post('large_content');
}
```